# Changes since last version in SonarQube LTS 5.6.6

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

We recently got SonarQube into our organisation as one of the main draws was that we would be able to track changes in technical debt over time. However, the core settings and default installation don't seem to provide for this. What do we need to do to be able to see changes in issues/coverage/etc. since our last build/a month ago/etc?

On others' dashboards I've seen it available as a convenient dropdown!

Comment: take a look at next.sonarqube.com (it is bleeding edge) but with sonarqube 6.x some nice features have been introduced which you can expirience there. Eg activity graphs. furthermore you should think about utilizing Quality gates, and think about your usage of the leak period!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQ LTS 5.6.6, use Timeline or History Table widgets.

Comment: I'll certainly give those a try, Any chance you could elaborate on what sets them apart from each other? And if you have insight on the actual dropdown I've observed with others', that be even neater :)

Comment: Depending on dashboard where u sue them, they are applied to full project or a module of the project.
It is true they give only a trend a not a true comparison between two periods.